# Booting 18.04 with 5.4.0-47 hwe kernel fails with "ALERT! UUID=<stuff> does not exist." error

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount

This has now happened to two hosts in the office when installing this particular kernel. I am able to boot these machines with an older kernel. I, like the people in:

[ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741792/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist)

[booting linux kernel 5.4.0-39, UUID does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254220/booting-linux-kernel-5-4-0-39-uuid-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)

have tried rebuilding initramfs to no effect. No hardware changes of any kind, simply updating the machine to the kernel revision in the question was enough to cause this problem to occur in both instances.

Any ideas? I have more machines that I will need to update at some point....

Comment: What command did you use to rebuild initramfs? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot` and `uname -r`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

From a live session run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1/mnt
sudo mkdir /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/mnt/dev
sudo mkdir /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /proc/mnt/proc
sudo mkdir /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /sys/mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo depmod `uname -r`
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub 
sudo reboot
```

Comment: That's a lot of stuff. Do you want to explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @heynnema: Start a live session. Chroot the installed system. Rebuild the new version of the installed kernel. To fix the error.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're doing... but the OP, and other readers, probably don't... so you need to add some verbiage to your answer... don't just say "try this"... with a bunch of `sudo` commands. Wouldn't give me a whole lot of confidence. Also, I'd use -c with the `update-initramfs` instead of -u.

Comment: chroot is not necessary. Booting with an older kernel is possible.